# I am trying to use material-ui... But not working error cannot read properties of null reading usecontext

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to use provider in index.js but I am getting error cannot read properties of null(use memo).... ...for this I am getting cannot read properties of null reading ....i refereed online channel but no one give me correct answer